# Use the stack in helper functions

Tags: c, memory-management

What's the best way to allocate an array on the stack that will be used by several helper functions/macros. Is there anyway to avoid passing pointers around?

Comment: If a variable is local to one function, the only way for other functions to access it is by a pointer.

Comment: @Barmar In C, scope of local variable is to the function only. Passing pointer to such variable will cause segmentation fault.

Comment: It is a question where "What are you actually trying to do?" is the best answer. If the array size is not known at compile time, you will need to use C Variable Length Array support, which may or may not be available. (Or alloca. I'm assuming this is straight C, not C++.)

Comment: Yes, I am using C99 variable length arrays. The approach I guess I will have to use is just have global pointers. Its ugly though, because that memory will only be valid in functions called by the initialization function.

Comment: @avery-whitaker: don't do that, it's terribly wrong. The best way to test for correctness is to have functions which don't access or mutate any shared state, i.e. pure functions (input -> function -> output). What is the problem with passing the parameter to the function?

Comment: @MilindDeore That's obviously not true, or functions like `strcpy()` would never work with local variables. The pointer allows it to access the local variable. You only get  undefined behavior if you try to use the pointer after the function where the variable was declared returns.

Comment: @avery-whitaker Why do you think you need to use *global* pointers? Pass the pointers as parameters to the functions.

Comment: @Barmar because I'd rather not have many functions with 10+ parameters each.

Comment: @avery-whitaker Package them in a `struct` so you only need one parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not. You will have to use pointers.